# Returning Integer from Macro

Tags: function, excel, return-value, vba

Im trying to cycle through certain rows in my excel spreadsheet. for the first group im trying to cycle through every 3 rows to see if its hidden and for the second for loop I am stepping through every 2. I basically want to add whats true through both loops and return that value. the "Return y" part is giving me an error.

```
Function FindHiddenRows() As Integer

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
y = 0

For x = 23 To 38 Step 3
    If Rows("x:x").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    Next x

For x = 40 To 46 Step 2
    If Rows("x:x").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    Next x

Return y

End Function
```

Comment: change `Rows("x:x")` to `Rows(x)`

Comment: And `Return y` to `FindHiddenRows = y`

Comment: It's not VB.Net please use correct tags :)

Comment: VB.NET doesnt have macros.  Please remove the tag

Answer (score 1):

to make it fast / short / easy:

```
Function FindHiddenRows() As Byte

  Dim x As Byte, y As Byte

  For x = 22 To 46 Step 2
    If x < 38 Then x = x + 1
    If Not Rows(x).Hidden Then y = y + 1
  Next

  FindHiddenRows = y

End Function
```